# Why approaching a value or getting closer and closer to a value means that we can get arbitrary close to that value?

Tags: limits

Why approaching a value means that we can get arbitrary close to that value?
Given two set:

$x = \{ 3, 2.5 , 2.04 , 2.03 , 2.02 , 2.001 , 2.0001, ... \}$

$y = \{ 4 , 6.25 , 5.76 , 4.25 , 4.025 , 4.001 , 4.00001 , ....\}$

As terms of the set $x$ gets closer and closer to $2$ ,terms of the set $y$ seems to be getting closer and closer to $4$ .But terms of set $x$ also seems to be getting closer and closer to $" values < 4 "$ like $3.999.. , 3.8999...$ etc. Then why we say the $4$ is the value the terms of set $y$ seems to be getting closer and closer to rather then some $value< 4$ ?

And also why we need to check for arbitrary number of terms to prove the existence of a value the terms of a set are getting closer and closer rather then just looking at bounded( finite ) number of terms of set ?

why can't we prove the existence of a value the sequence is getting closer and closer just but checking finite number of terms of a sequence rather than looking at arbitrary number of terms of a sequence?

from the given set above ,why is it that we say the value the terms of set $y$ is getting closer and closer to is $4$ rather than $values < 4$ even though it does closer and closer to $values < 4$ ?

why when formalizing the idea of a sequence getting closer closer to particular value ,it is defined the to check the existence of the value we are getting closer and closer to ,we need to look at arbitrary number of terms rather than finite number of terms?

So, My question is that why approaching a value means that we can get arbitrary close to that value i.e why getting closer and closer to a value means that we can get as close as we want to that value?

Why the notion of approaching a value or getting closer and closer to a value means that we can get arbitrary close not just sufficiently close to that value?

why as $f(x)$ approaches $L$ as $x$ approaches $a$ means that we can make the values of $f(x)$ as close to $L$ as we would like by making $x$ as close enough to $a$.

Comment: Approaching a value doesn't mean that it's the limit. For instance, $a_n=1+\frac1n$ approaches 0 with each new term but it's not the limit.

Comment: *not just sufficiently close* (at end of your question) --- One problem with this particular phrase is that for it to have meaning, criteria/conditions for what is sufficient need to be given. What criteria do you have in mind?

Comment: These are all questions of definitions. We don’t define “closer and closer” for a reason. We also don’t define “approaching,” although we sometimes use “approaching” when discussing limits. If you don’t follow definitions, and just use words as they seem to you they *should* mean, you won’t get far understanding limits.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro By sufficiently close ,I  meant that we check the existence of a limit just by looking at finite number of neighborhood.

Comment: @Anuj "*we check the existence of a limit just by looking at finite number of neighborhood*" $\;-\;$ No, that's definitely not so, and you don't explain why you think it would be. "*as f(x) approaches L as x approaches a means that we can make the values of f(x) as close to L as we would like by making x as close enough to a*" $\;-\;$ No, that's not the case, as pointed out in the very first comment above.